# How to add a setMyLocationEnabled button on OSMap?

Tags: osmdroid

Can we enable a 'GotoMyLocation' button on OSMDroid like `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` on GoogleMap?

I didn't find such feature in MapView class.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create one of these

`org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay mylocation = new MyLocationNewOverlay(...);`

Add it to your MapView

`mMapView.getOverlays().add(mylocation);`

Then try 
`mylocation.enableFollowLocation();`

Comment: enableMyLocation() or enableFollowLocation() are not what I'm looking for, because the 1st one add a little chap locating me and the second one add an arrow showing the direction I follow. I want a button which allows me to go back where I am if I scrolled the map anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

To set your current location use, LOCATION_SERVICE of LocationManager. This will listen your gps location and will set your center to the present location.

```
LocationManager myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListenerProxy llp=new LocationListenerProxy(myLocationManager);
        llp.startListening(gpsLocationListener, 1, 1) ;
```

place this code in your onCreate Activity and then define locationlistener in a different class

```
public final LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location){  
          textView.setText(location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
          Log.d("Location Changed >>> ", location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
      }
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
     };
```

Comment: interesting Rudra but again it's not what I'm looking for and I'm so surprised that I cannot get the answer as this is a so common feature on Google map. When you use SetEnableMyLocation(true), between other things you get a 'locate me' button on the upper right corner of the map to ask to center the map on your position. Usefull when you scrolled the map to look at the displayed area for anything you want. So, I'm looking for the option to display such button.

Comment: I don't think this feature exist in osmdroid library. but, you can create a button overlay on the map and attach the above code to that button.

Comment: If anyone wonders, the [author's solution seems to be here](https://github.com/2ndGAB/OSMCenterToMyPosition) and there is also an example implementation based off of that solution with [this osmdroid commit](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/commit/b2789e61c188c37335e1d2fbd7bf6045057f87d7)