# how to get user location without google play services for osmdroid

Tags: java, android, location, osmdroid

I am looking for a way to get user's location without google play services for osmdroid maps. Because I don't wnat My application to be dependent on google play services, I don't want to use it.

What are your suggestions?

ps: I don't mind for my app to take long to detect the location but I prefer to show the user its last known position and then update it in a while.

Comment: Hi there, I don't know If you can obtain location other than using google-play-services. I have done an example using OSM and google-play-location service [here](https://github.com/zurche/osm-droid-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/az/osmdroidprop/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Just follow the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) to use the platform location API in the `android.location` package.

Comment: duplication question, answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34100938/1203182